# express.js handling video stream received from POST request?

Tags: node.js, express

The problem I seem to be running into is I don't know how to setup express.js to handle the video data its receiving from the POST request.

When I start the stream with ffmpeg. the server receives the request just fine. I just need help keeping the connection open and getting the video data in the express.js POST req.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the event for the incoming request:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('---start');

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('---end');
  }

});
```